# Replace DIV Element When Clicked On It 3 Times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, element

I want to replace a specific div element with a different one, when it has reached 3 clicks on it. That is the only task, I am trying to accomplish with the code.

I have tried looking at some code that does this but all of them replace it with get go, they don't give you a number amount to specify when to replace it with.

Example: `<div id="1"></div>` has been clicked on 3 times by a user. Once it exceeds that amount replace it with `<div id="3"></div>`

Comment: So have you made an attempt at introducing this counter yourself? Can you, at least, write the pseudo-code for such an interaction? Is there a specific problem you're stuck with?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527)

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is to start listening click events on the first div and count them.
The below code shows this concept. Firstly we put first div into variable to be able to create event listeners on it and also create `count` variable with initial value: 0. Then pre-make the second div, which will replace the first one later.
And the last part is also obvious: put event listener on a `div1` which will increment `count` and check if it is equal 3 each time click happens.

```js
const div1 = document.querySelector('#id-1');
let count = 0;

// pre-made second div for future replacement
const divToReplace = document.createElement('div');
divToReplace.id = 'id-2';
divToReplace.innerText = 'div 2';

div1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  count ++;
  if (count === 3) {
    div1.parentNode.replaceChild(divToReplace, div1);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="id-1"> div 1 </div>
```

Note that this approach is easy to understand, but the code itself is not the best, especially if you will need to reuse that logic. The below example is a bit more complicated - we create a function which takes 2 arguments: one for element to track and another - the element to replace with. Such approach will allow us to reuse functionality if needed.

```js
function replaceAfter3Clicks(elem, newElem) {
    let count = 0;
    div1.addEventListener('click', () => {
        count ++;
        if (count === 3) {
            elem.parentNode.replaceChild(newElem, elem);
        }
    });
}

const div1 = document.querySelector('#id-1');

// pre-made second div for future replacement
const div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.id = 'id-2';
div2.innerText = 'div 2';

replaceAfter3Clicks(div1, div2);
```

```html
<div id="id-1"> div 1 </div>
```

Comment: I've just added some comments. I hope, that it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the *id* attribute is not a good idea, instead you can use ***data-*** attribute like the following way:

```js
var count = 0; // Declare a variable as counter
$('#1').click(function(){
  count++; // Increment the couter by 1 in each click
  if(count == 3) // Check the counter
    $(this).data('id', '3'); // Set the data attribute
  console.log($(this).data('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" data-id="1">Click</div>
```

Comment: This only works if you use jQuery. However, the code could be easily refactored to work without this dependency as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a JavaScript function that keeps track how often you clicked on a specific DOM element (i. e. the `div` element with `id="1"`). As soon as the element was clicked three times, it will be replaced by another DOM element which can be created in JavaScript as well.

```js
var clicks = 0;

function trackClick(el) {
  clicks++;

  if(clicks === 3) {
    var newEl = document.createElement('div');
    newEl.textContent = 'Div3';
    newEl.id = '3';
    el.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, el);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="1" onclick="trackClick(this)">Div1</div>
```

In case you should use a library like jQuery or have another HTML structure, please specify your question to improve this code snippet so that it fits for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you know, how to use JQuery, just put a click event handler on your div 1. On that handler, increment a click counter to 3. If it reaches 3, replace the div with JQuery again.

If there are multiple divs to replace, use an array of counters instead of a single one, or modify a user-specific data attribute via JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Using native JavaScript, rather than relying upon library (for all the benefits that might offer), the following approach is possible:

```js
// A named function to handle the 'click' event on the relevant elements;
// the EventObject is passed in, automatically, from EventTarget.addEventListener():
const replaceOn = (event) => {

  // caching the element that was clicked (because I'm using an Arrow function
  // syntax we can't use 'this' to get the clicked element):
  let el = event.target,

    // creating a new <div> element:
    newNode = document.createElement('div'),

    // retrieving the current number of clicks set on the element, after this
    // number becomes zero we replace the element. Here we use parseInt() to
    // convert the string representation of the number into a base-10 number:
    current = parseInt(el.dataset.replaceOn, 10);

  // here we update the current number with the decremented number (we use the
  // '--' operator to reduce the number by one) and then we update the
  // data-replace-on attribute value with the new number:
  el.dataset.replaceOn = --current;

  // here we discover if that number is now zero:
  if (current === 0) {
    // if so, we write some content to the created <div> element: 
    newNode.textContent = "Original element has been replaced.";

    // and here we use Element.replaceWith() to replace the current
    // 'el' element with the new newNode element:
    el.replaceWith(newNode);
  }
};

// here we use the [data-replace-on] attribute-selector to search
// through the document for all elements with that attribute, and
// use NodeList.forEach() to iterate over that NodeList:
document.querySelectorAll('[data-replace-on]').forEach(

  // using an Arrow function we pass a reference to the current
  // Node of the NodeList to the function, and here we use
  // EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the replaceOn function
  // (note the deliberate lack of parentheses) to handle the
  // 'click' event:
  (element) => element.addEventListener('click', replaceOn)
);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

div[data-replace-on] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div[data-replace-on]::before {
  content: attr(data-replace-on);
}
```

```html
<div data-replace-on="3"></div>
<div data-replace-on="13"></div>
<div data-replace-on="1"></div>
<div data-replace-on="21"></div>
<div data-replace-on="1"></div>
<div data-replace-on="6"></div>
<div data-replace-on="4"></div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute-selectors (`[attribute=attribute-value]`)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-selectors-3-20180130/#attribute-representation).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`ChildNode.replaceWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).